# Read excel and reformat the multi-index headers in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given a excel file with format as follows:

[image]

Reading with `pd.read_clipboard`, I get:

```
   year      2018 Unnamed: 2      2019 Unnamed: 4
0  city  quantity      price  quantity      price
1    bj        10          2         4          7
2    sh         6          8         3          4
```

Just wondering if it's possible to convert to the following format with Pandas:

```
   year city  quantity  price
0  2018   bj        10      2
1  2019   bj         4      7
2  2018   sh         6      8
3  2019   sh         3      4
```

Comment: Is possible use `df = pd.read_excel(file, header=[0,1], index_col=[0])` ?

Comment: thanks a lot, I’ll test and let you know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think here is best convert excel file to `DataFrame` with `MultiIndex in columns` and first column as index:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, header=[0,1], index_col=[0])

print (df)
year     2018           2019      
city quantity price quantity price
bj         10     2        4     7
sh          6     8        3     4

print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([('2018', 'quantity'),
            ('2018',    'price'),
            ('2019', 'quantity'),
            ('2019',    'price')],
           names=['year', 'city'])
```

Then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), change order of levels by [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html), set index and columns names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and last convert `index` to columns, and if encessary convert year to integers:

```
df1 = (df.stack(0)
         .swaplevel(0,1)
         .rename_axis(index=['year','city'], columns=None)
         .reset_index()
         .assign(year=lambda x: x['year'].astype(int)))
print (df1)
   year city  price  quantity
0  2018   bj      2        10
1  2019   bj      7         4
2  2018   sh      8         6
3  2019   sh      4         3
```